# Is it possible to take a new visitor to the site to a disclaimer page and then return them to their previous page?

Tags: redirect, terms

I am new to WordPress and I am looking to add a disclaimer page where they either "Agree" to some terms/conditions or "Do Not Aggree". When a visitor to the site enters, they are taken to the page where they then either Agree or do not agree and then they are returned to their previous page. Is this possible and if so where do I start? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to WordPress I assume you do not have coding experience to be able to code a popup using Javascript on your own. For that reason I recommend using a popup plugin such as the one called WP Terms. There are many plugins that can help you do that.

Otherwise you can set your homepage as a regular page, add two buttons on it, then each button redirect to your content.

Comment: I do have prior  JavaScript experience and could possibly code a popup. But I am looking to take them to a separate page that has the disclaimer rather than a popup.